Handling Rails Timestamps with Mixed Time Zones with legacy records
I'm facing a challenge with handling timestamps in my Rails application. Currently, my app stores timestamps in UTC in the database and displays them based on the configured timezone, which works fine for new records. However, I have a large number of old records stored in PST and EST time zones, and when Rails processes these records, it incorrectly converts them to UTC, leading to incorrect results.
With millions of old records across multiple tables, I'm looking for a solution that can properly handle both new and old data. Ideally, I need a way to either:
Configure Rails to store PST/EST timestamps instead of UTC for both new and old records.
Implement a strategy that allows Rails to correctly interpret and display old timestamps without altering the stored data.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a good approach to resolve this?
I configured Rails to store PST timestamp as below but it stores EST:
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)' 
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Insertion query with EST timestamp:
TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  UnitType Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `test_units` (`name`, `unittype`, `recordtime`, `deleteflag`) VALUES ('test', 'test', '2024-11-11 12:23:10.200677', FALSE)
  TRANSACTION (1.3ms)  COMMIT


You will be fighting rails every step of the way -- instead of trying to slap a bandaid on in the app, I would update the data to be in UTC.  It's a one off and much less fragile.
